# Why does my chdir to a filehandle not work in Perl?

Tags: perl, chdir

When I try a "chdir" with a filehandle as argument, "chdir" returns 0 and a `pwd` returns still the same directory. Should that be so?

I tried this, because in the documentation to chdir I found:

> "On systems that support fchdir, you
>   might pass a file handle or directory
>   handle as argument. On systems that
>   don't support fchdir, passing handles
>   produces a fatal error at run time."

Given later:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.010;
use strict;
use Cwd;

say cwd();  # /home/mm
open( my $fh, '>', '/home/mm/Documents/foto.jpg' ) or die $!;
say chdir $fh;  # 0
say cwd();  # /home/mm
```

I thought that this would maybe chdir to the directory of the file - but no DWIM for me here.

Comment: Which language/environment is this?

Comment: Where's your small demonstration script that shows the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It also says

```
It returns true upon success, false otherwise.
```

meaning that your call to `chdir` failed. Check the `$!` variable for a clue about what happened. Since you didn't get a fatal runtime error, you don't have to worry about that last paragraph about `fchdir`.

---

Running a couple of tests, I see `chdir FILEHANDLE` works when `FILEHANDLE` refers to a directory, but not to a regular file. Hope that helps:

```
  open(FH, "<", "/tmp/file");  # assume this file exists
  chdir FH and print "Success 1\n" or warn "Fail 1: $!\n";
  open(FH, "<", "/tmp");
  chdir FH and print "Success 2\n" or warn "Fail 2: $!\n";
  opendir(FH, "/tmp");
  chdir FH and print "Success 3\n" or warn "Fail 3: $!\n";
```

```
  Fail 1: Not a directory
  Success 2
  Success 3
```

Comment: Tsk tsk, you're using a global typeglob rather than a local lexical :)

Comment: I didn't know, that filehandle can refer to  a directory.

Comment: @sid_com It's not a useful feature, but at some level of abstraction a Un*x directory is just another file

Comment: Sorry Ether, it's an old bad habit that I still indulge on short throwaway programs. At least I started using the 3 arg version of `open`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `perl`? Which operating system?

5.10.1 on Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

# have to use a file because Windows does not let 
# open directories as files
# only done so I can illustrate the fatal error on
# a platform where fchdir is not implemented

open my $fh, '<', 'e:/home/test.txt'
    or die "Cannot open file: $!";

chdir $fh
    or die "Cannot chdir using filehandle: $!";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> k
The fchdir function is unimplemented at C:\Temp\k.pl line 9.
```

5.10.1 on Linux (`/home/sinan/test` is a directory):

```
$ cat k.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Cwd;

open my $fh, '<', '/home/sinan/test'
    or die "Cannot open file: $!";

chdir $fh
    or die "Cannot chdir using filehandle: $!";

print getcwd, "\n";

$ ./k.pl
/home/sinan/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Windows doesn't support fchdir and it is in fact a fatal error there:

```
perl -we"opendir my $fh, 'temp'; chdir $fh or print 'foo'"
```

produces a fatal error. So it looks like on systems that have no support for fchdir at all it works to spec. Looks like the wording could be cleared up especially the word "might."